# Setting channel width with rt2870: iw: Device or resource busy (-16)

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, debian, 802.11n

I only now found out that my USB WiFi stick is capable of n-WiFi (Edimax EW-7711USn), so naturally, I'd like to get the highest possible speed from it. My link is great, 29dbM and 70/70 quality, but `iw dev wlan1 info` reports

```
Interface wlan1
    ifindex 5
    wdev 0x200000001
    addr 80:1f:02:48:79:0c
    type managed
    wiphy 2
    channel 4 (2427 MHz), width: ***20 MHz***, center1: 2427 MHz
```

I. e. I'm only getting half the Tx rates I could, according to `iw phy`:

```
    Band 1:
            Capabilities: 0x172
                    HT20/***HT40***
                    Static SM Power Save
                    RX Greenfield
                    RX HT20 SGI
                    RX HT40 SGI
                    RX STBC 1-stream
                    Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
                    No DSSS/CCK HT40
```

(I'm honestly not sure what the lines about SGI, DSSS and CCK mean in this context, but Google doesn't spit out any related problems.)

Now when I try to change to HT40 with `iw --debug dev wlan1 set channel 4 HT40+` - which seems to be the *only* way to set that in Linux at all?! -, I get:

```
-- Debug: Sent Message:
--------------------------   BEGIN NETLINK MESSAGE ---------------------------
  [NETLINK HEADER] 16 octets
    .nlmsg_len = 44
    .type = 26 <0x1a>
    .flags = 5 <REQUEST,ACK>
    .seq = 1408886294
    .port = 20560
  [GENERIC NETLINK HEADER] 4 octets
    .cmd = 2
    .version = 0
    .unused = 0
  [PAYLOAD] 24 octets
    08 00 03 00 05 00 00 00 08 00 26 00 7b 09 00 00 ..........&.{...
    08 00 27 00 03 00 00 00                         ..'.....
---------------------------  END NETLINK MESSAGE   ---------------------------
-- Debug: Received Message:
--------------------------   BEGIN NETLINK MESSAGE ---------------------------
  [NETLINK HEADER] 16 octets
    .nlmsg_len = 64
    .type = 2 <ERROR>
    .flags = 0 <>
    .seq = 1408886294
    .port = 20560
  [ERRORMSG] 20 octets
    .error = -16 "Device or resource busy"
  [ORIGINAL MESSAGE] 16 octets
    .nlmsg_len = 16
    .type = 26 <0x1a>
    .flags = 5 <REQUEST,ACK>
    .seq = 1408886294
    .port = 20560
---------------------------  END NETLINK MESSAGE   ---------------------------
command failed: Device or resource busy (-16)
```

With HT40-, it just fails with "invalid argument". I tried stopping `network-manager` and `ifconfig wlan1 down`, but `wlan1` stays busy. What can I do to get 40 MHz channel width? 72 Mbps is annoyingly slow as a connection to a NAS...

System information: Debian Sid, dist-upgraded last week, 3.15-10.dmz.1-liquorix-amd64. `lsmod | grep rt2`:

```
rt2800usb              20564  0 
rt2x00usb              11702  1 rt2800usb
rt2800lib              78803  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              43922  3 rt2x00usb,rt2800lib,rt2800usb
mac80211              521698  3 rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb,rt2800lib
cfg80211              478903  2 mac80211,rt2x00lib
crc_ccitt               1715  1 rt2800lib
```

And it's using rt2870.bin as a firmware according to dmesg. Compiling the driver edimax provides on their site fails because it's from 2008.

Comment: So, are you trying to modify the WiFi client or access point? Because you'll have to set the latter to use 40 MHz channels.

Comment: Thanks for responding! The latter is set to 20/40 MHz for both 2.4 and 5 GHz, so that should work. I got a cheap dual band stick now which uses the same firmware, and interestingly, it is unable to use wide channels on 2,4 GHz as well, but it works on 5 GHz. (Very badly, lots of packet loss, but that may be the hardware.) So it's either the router's fault or the part of the driver that governs 2,4 GHz use; though I'd hope there would be some clearer error messages if it's the former.